# Convert List<Class> to Class... to get declared method

Tags: java, reflection, java-11

I am trying to get a method of a class I load during runtime using [`Class.getDeclaredMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class...)). The parameters for `Class.getDeclaredMethod` are `String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes`. I have the `parameterTypes` as a List.

How do I pass the `parameterTypes` from my list to the `Class.getDeclaredMethod`?

I tried `(Class[]) paramterTypes.toArray()` and it didn't work.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, why not use `.getDeclaredMethod("<name>", List.class)`? Can you update the question with the exact method signature that you want to look up and the code you've tried?

Comment: I have a list of the parameterTypes. List is not the parameterType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. It is simply

```
Class[] paramsAr = new Class[parameterTypes.size()];
parameterTypes.toArray(paramsAr);
```

Comment: When you have a chance, please remember to click the check at the top left to mark this as the correct answer

Comment: Just use `Class[] paramsAr = parameterTypes.toArray(new Class[0]);`

Comment: @Holger the docs (for arraylist) state:  "If the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this list." So unless I am misunderstanding, it is actually worse than what I demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: It’s simpler and basically does the same. If you are concerned about the ephemeral zero length array, I suggest reading [this great article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/).

Comment: @Holger Yes it seems like I was missing something. You have succeeded in both enlightening me and making my head hurt. This is what I get for asking questions 8-|